# Rewrite one of the async methods into one that uses promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

How can I rewrite my callback into promises that using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module? For example if I have the following code

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

or

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

Comment: What is result of `async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);` ? , Can create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ? What is expected result of utilizing async module ?

Comment: Those are two of the `async` methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Rewrite `async.parallel`

You wouldn't use any callback functions for this, but you would create yoursel promises for all the tasks that you want to run. Then, you could await all of those using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([promiseMaker1(), promiseMaker2()]).then(callback);
```

> Rewrite `async.waterfall`

For this, you'd use the most primitive promise method: [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). It is used for chaining promises, passing a callback to a promise and getting a new promise for the result of the callback. Notice however that promises always resolve with a single value only, so your `nodeback(null, 'one', 'two')` example won't work. You'll have to use an array or object instead.

```
Promise.resolve(['one', 'two']).then(function(args) {
    // args[0] now equals 'one' and args[1] now equals 'two'
    return Promise.resolve('three'); // you can (and usually do) return promises from callbacks
}).then(function(arg1) {
    // arg1 now equals 'three'
    return 'done'; // but plain values also work
}).then(function(result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `Promise.all` that comes built in in almost every promise library in one way or another - and in particular in native and bluebird promises:

```
function fn1(){
    return Promise.resolve(1);        
}
function fn1(){
    return Promise.resolve(2);        
}

Promise.all([fn1(), fn2()]).then(function(results){
    //access results in array
    console.log(results); // [1,2]
});
```